# how to read the particular keyword from the given string

Tags: java, android, json

I am using the following code

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "success",
    "token": "94529e5dbc6234fc3bbfce7406b8dde9"
}
```

I have to print the token in the output screen.

Comment: Give us some more of your code

Comment: That's a JSON string, use a library like jackson or gson to parse into an object, then do whatever you need with it.

Comment: it is json. use JsonObject to parse it.

Answer (score 3):

That is a simple JSON string, you can use a [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) to parse it.

For example:

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
String token = root.getString("token");
```